# Sum of two array field result pass to another array field and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am looking to generate a report, which show me Used stock and balance stock from a database, but I am getting the wrong output; *balance stock* result will come from *used stock* Subtract Total stock.
For example :
 *Total Stock*=1000 
and used stock in an array-like (100,150,50,100)
Now,
I want to count each *balance stock* against *Used stock* should show 
  output should show

```
 0     1000
100    900
150    750
050    700
100    600
```

```
$A=100;
$B=$data; (value from  database in array )
  /////**  suppose $B[]=100;
               $B[]=200;
                $B[]=300;
$c=count($B);
foreach($c as $key => $c){
$result=$A+$B[$key];

echo"$result";
}



?>`
```

expected output is

```
 200  
 400
 600
```

Comment: `foreach($c as $key => $c){` where is `$c` coming from? The first one

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is unclear. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: $c is counting number of array

Comment: @Yateen Welcome to StackOverflow!  There is no need to add "please help" to your question or your comments.  It is assumed you are posting here because you are seeking help.  Your question is being downvoted because it is not clear what you are asking.  Try to edit your question and put more detail in about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i got the solution from another website.....

Answer (score 0):

```
@$pl=$_POST['pl'];
@$is=$_POST['is'];


$input = 10000;


$remainder = 0;

foreach($pl AS $num =>$num ){
    $remainder = ($remainder == 0) ? $input : $remainder;
    $out = $remainder + $pl[$num];
    if($out < 0){
        break;
    }
    $remainder = $out;  ?>
```